# Android SDK has not been setup in the preferences

Tags: android

I have adt-bundle-linux-x86 package and working for a month, its works fine till yesterday. But Today eclipse shows me the ADT update screen as following:[image]

while checking update i get "**No updates were found**"

But i could not create a new project,use the existing project and even could not open the AVD.
The AVD Manager throws "**Location of the Android SDK has not been setup in the preferences**."

The Window->Preference->Android window does not load any Android SDKs (few days before it was present). But still there is present the **Android-8,Android-14,Android-16 and 17** folders in the following path "**/home/murali/adt-bundle-linux-x86/sdk**".

I have spend several hours to solve the problem but i couldn't get solution and find out the reason why the problem occur. i have struggled with my works, please help me.

This is my Preference window(herewith i attached for better understanding)
[image: Preference window with error]

please help me to solve the SDK and ADT problems.

Comment: Which version of Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try re installing the ADT/SDK? A fresh install is probably best. Here's the [link](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) to download if you didn't already know. Hope i helped somewhat

Answer (score 2):

I have download new SDK bundle instead of spending time for find out the reason.